# What can I do about clumping?

Tags: gran-turismo-3-a-spec, gran-turismo-series

In Gran Turismo (all versions, but especially 3, right now), I frequently run into problems with getting stuck in the middle of the pack -- especially in races where all 6 cars are the same model, and hence, roughly the same speed.

Once I get a chance to pull out ahead, then I'm fine.  But if I'm stuck in or near the pack and can't just accelerate out, I'll get into the middle of a corner, and then get smashed into the wall by the car behind me (the infamous "Zombie A.I."), and then before I can escape, smashed again by the next car, and the next.

So very quickly, instead of a close race for first or second place, I'm back in 6th place by a couple seconds.  And I have no trouble driving well enough to close the gap, but as soon as I'm in the pack again, I get smashed into the walls again.

It feels mostly like luck whether I can squeeze through and get #1 instead of #6, and I think that probably shouldn't be the case.  What can I do to break through?

EDIT: In some cases, if the timing works out just right, I can pre-emptively ram other cars against the wall, which delays them enough for me to get past.  As Fezzik says, though, "My way's not very sportsmanlike".

Comment: Better cat litter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rubbing is racing.
Be on the inside of the turn and use your opponent to help you make the turn.  Yes, this usually leaves your opponent eating wall; just like they do to you when you're on the outside.  Only pass on the outside when you've got a speed advantage.  You can get that speed advantage by tuning your car more than the opponents do.
All my experience with the series leads me to only those two options; either be more aggressive or be faster.  Or both.  Both is good.  But being aggressive is easy and being faster takes a lot of skill and practice.
Make your choice!

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot to it really. Slipsteams help you go faster in a straight line - less air resistance (so drive right behind your opponent in the straights!) and in the corners you want to take the shortest line - so try to tuck to the inside of the corner. I.e. on a left hander, like the first corner of deep forest, be sure to be just next to or one wheel on top of the rumble strips as it is the shortest route. Dont be overdoing it though as the rumble strips can cause cars with firm suspension to lose grip!